# How can I plot self organizing maps with neighborhood connections through python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I developed a som varient with python and it is time to visualize the som units but I need to reflect the neighborhood connections as well in 2d lattice of som. I can easily use scatter plot of matplotlib but I need to show the connections. How can I ad these edges to that plot or is there any other tool in python to get used?

Answer (score 0):

I think with [`NetworkX`](https://networkx.github.io/index.html) you could create connected element and draw it. See: [NetworX Gallery](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/gallery.html)